# Make limit line always visible on mpandroidchart

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am making an app which retrieves data from a database and shows it on a barchart. I have defined a limit line using the provided methods at 30f (on the Y axis).

The problem is, that I want that limit line to be always shown and it only becomes visible when one of the Graph's Bars raises above that value (30f).

Is there a way to always show it?

I have tried with the zoom functions with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Modify the `YAxis` display range to your needs: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/YAxis-(YLabels)

Especially those methods should help:

- `setAxisMaxValue(float max)`: Set a custom maximum value for this axis. If set, this value will not be calculated automatically depending on the provided data.
- `setAxisMinValue(float min)`: Set a custom minimum value for this axis. If set, this value will not be calculated automatically depending on the provided data.

Comment: this is showing as deprecated and as per document there is no other alternative added, if i set custom values to axisMax and axisMin it mess up the entire graph shows wrong plotting but only limit line is correctly drawn